# Target all the label inside a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-traversal

i have the follwing setup. here i am trying to add custom radio and checkboxes.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).forEach((tr,index)=>{
  var mark=document.createElement("span");
  Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll("input")).forEach((inp,index1)=>{
    if(inp.type=="radio"){
      mark.classList.add("dotmark");
      inp.parentNode.appendChild(mark);
    }
    else{
      mark.classList.add("checkmark");
      inp.parentNode.appendChild(mark);//instead append in to the next td's label tag
    }
  })
})
```

```css
span{
width:20px;
height:20px;
background:#ccc;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table id="tab1" class="table labelCustom">
   <tbody>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' id='one' name='name'></td><td><label for='one'>example</label></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' id='two' name='name'></td><td><label for='two'>example</label></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' id='three' name='name'></td><td><label for='three'>example</label></td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

i want the dyanamically created span element to be inserted in the label tag. now it is inserting it in the inputs td.

Note: the class of the span element is depeneding on the input type.

Comment: `inp.parentNode` is the `td`. Maybe try `inp.closest('tr').querySelector('label')`.

Comment: i want the span element to be inserted in the next td's label tag

Comment: Further to connexo's comment: `inp.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('label').appendChild('mark')`; your posted script shows that you seem to understand JavaScript pretty well, so am I missing something in your question? What did you need help with? Also, your comment implies you only want the `<span>` appended to the `<label>` if the `input` is not of  `type=radio`?

Comment: @DavidThomas, thanks, i tried 'nextSibling' but it does't worked but nextSiblingElement worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, among many, is the following:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).forEach((tr, index) => {
  var mark = document.createElement("span");
  Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll("input")).forEach((inp, index1) => {

    // caching the <label> element for readability:
    let label = inp.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('label');

    // adding the class-name based on the result of the ternary operator,
    // if the input.type is equal to 'radio' we return the class-name of
    // 'dotmark', otherwise we return 'checkmark':
    mark.classList.add(inp.type === 'radio' ? 'dotmark' : 'checkmark');

    // appending the element held within the 'mark' variable:
    label.appendChild(mark);
  })
})
```

```css
span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}

span.dotmark {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

span.checkmark {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<table id="tab1" class="table labelCustom">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='radio' id='one' name='name'></td>
      <td><label for='one'>example</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='radio' id='two' name='name'></td>
      <td><label for='two'>example</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='radio' id='three' name='name'></td>
      <td><label for='three'>example</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='four' name='differentName'></td>
      <td><label for='four'>example</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As an addendum, from the comment by the OP to the question:

> I tried `nextSibling` but it does't worked but `nextSiblingElement` worked.

The difference between the two is that `nextSibling` returns any sibling, whether it's a text-node, element-node or any other, whereas `nextElementSibling`, as the name implies, returns the next sibling which is also an element-node.

References:

- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).
- [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling).

Comment: *whether it's a text-node, element-node or any other* What nodetypes are there other than `TextNode` and `ElementNode`?

Comment: Oh there's [quite a few](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType#Node_type_constants), though which might be returned by `nextSibling` I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
inp.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('label')
```

instead of just

```
inp.parentNode
```

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).forEach((tr,index)=>{
  var mark=document.createElement("span");
  Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll("input")).forEach((inp,index1)=>{
    if(inp.type=="radio"){
      mark.classList.add("dotmark");
      inp.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('label').appendChild(mark);
    }
    else{
      mark.classList.add("checkmark");
      inp.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('label').appendChild(mark);
    }
  })
})
```

```css
span{
width:20px;
height:20px;
background:#ccc;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table id="tab1" class="table labelCustom">
   <tbody>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' id='one' name='name'></td><td><label for='one'>example</label></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' id='two' name='name'></td><td><label for='two'>example</label></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' id='three' name='name'></td><td><label for='three'>example</label></td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested loops, once on tr and then on input, since you have just one input and label inside each tr, so you can combine these into single query as `tr input`. And, you don't need to use `Array.from`, since `querySelectorAll` returns `NodeList` which already have a `forEach` function.

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr input').forEach(input => {
    const span = document.createElement('span')
    span.classList.add(input.type === 'radio' ? 'dotmark' : 'checkmark')
    input.parentNode.nextElementSibling.appendChild(span)
})
```